# Mule ESB db template query is throwing error

Tags: mule-esb

I am working on migrating to Mule ESB to 3.9.1.
I have the following database stored procedure configuration in my mule config:

```
  <db:generic-config name="configuration" url="${url}" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="My Generic Configuration"></db:generic-config>
<db:template-query name="mystoredProcedure" doc:name="Template Query">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ call [dbo].[myStoredProcecure](:fileName, :description) }]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:template-query>
```

When I deploy the app I see the following error:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with name 'fileName', used in the query text, does not match any defined query parameter name defined in the query template
```

Is the naming different for "fileName" or does it need to be declared somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In means there is no parameter called `fileName` in the template that you created. The names in your query and template need to match up exactly.